# Getting custom file name for datatable after page submit

Tags: jquery, datatables

My website has multiple pages with each page having its own set of select input.  Upon changing the select input and 'clicking submit' a new data table is rendered.  I am using the following script to export the generated data table to different formats.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
      $('#tabdat').DataTable({
          dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                ],
          "pageLength": 50
      });
    });
</script>
```

This works fine, but it takes the title of the page as the file name.  Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34953557/setting-up-a-custom-file-name-datatables-export-excelhtml5-with-a-select-text/35113752) example, I modified the code.  I am providing the code again continuity.

```
<select id="filename">
    <option value="filenameA">filename A</option>
    <option value="filenameB">filename B</option>
    <option value="filenameC">filename C</option>
</select>

buttons : [
   {
    extend: 'excelHtml5',
    title: 'filenameA', //default filename
    init: function(dt, node, config) {
        $("#filename").on('change', function() {
            config.title = this.value;
        })
    }
},
```

This works perfectly fine, when i change the select input option and click on the excel export button.  But since my table gets generated only after page submit, the name gets reset to the default 'filenameA' irrespective of the change.  How do I take the value of the select input for my data table file name upon page submit?

Comment: See this -> **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758037/dynamically-changing-the-file-name-of-jquery-datatables-exported-excel-using-but** there is no other workaround.

Comment: @davidkonrad Many thanks...since by default the data table takes the page title, and I was also ok with altering my page title with that of the select Input value, I simply changed the `document.title` to the select input value.  It works flawlessly ;-).