# Datatable pdf customize not picking dynamic value into title

Tags: php, jquery, datatables-1.10

I have the following datatable which I send some dynamic value into its title. But it doesnt seem to be picking them. Also the title cause my file name to change too. How to enable the dynamic value are passed correctly into the pdf. Here is how I am doing it title: `'Vehicle ID:'+$("#vehicleID").val()+'\nDate Start:',` But it just appear as `Vehicle IDDate Start` at the top. How to also add footer and page numbering?

```
var oTable = $('#dashboardGrid').dataTable({
                    "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
                    "aoColumnDefs": [ { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0,1 ] }],
                        "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
              "ajax": {
                        "url": "getData.php",
                        "type": "POST",
                        "data": function(d) {
                            d.vID = $("#vehicleID").val()
                            d.startDateTime = startDateTimeFinal
                            d.endDateTime = endDateTimeFinal
                         }                

                    },
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    lengthMenu: [
            [ 10, 25, 50, -1 ],
            [ '10 rows', '25 rows', '50 rows', 'Show all' ]
        ],
        buttons: [
           'pageLength', 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print',
           {
           extend: 'pdf',
                        title: 'Vehicle ID:'+$("#vehicleID").val()+'\nDate Start:',
                        text: 'Pdf',
                        orientation: 'landscape',
                        pageSize: 'A4',
                        exportOptions: {
                        columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 5 ]
                        },
                        customize: function ( doc ) {
                        doc.content[1].table.widths = [
                        '5%',
                        '30%',
                        '30%',
                        '10%',
                        '10%'

                        ]
                        }
           }
```

Here is my full list of .js included.

```
   <script src="dt/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dt/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dt/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dt/datatables.net-buttons-bs/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dt/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dt/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dt/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dt/datatables.net-fixedheader/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dt/datatables.net-keytable/js/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dt/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dt/datatables.net-responsive-bs/js/responsive.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="dt/datatables.net-scroller/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dt/datatable-plugin/fnReloadAjax.js"></script>
    <script src="dt/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dt/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dt/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
```

Here is my temporary link http:///testReport1.php

Comment: I am not sure: Do you want to change the title of the pdf, or the filename - or both...?

Comment: I want both how to do that and also page number at the footer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buttons seem now to recognize function attributes. At least with version 1.3.1 as I refer to below. Once a little [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758037/dynamically-changing-the-file-name-of-jquery-datatables-exported-excel-using-but) was needed in order to set the filename or title dynamically. This works with 1.10.15 and buttons 1.3.1 :

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [{
    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
    filename: function() {
      return $('#filename').val()      
    },
    title: function() {
      return $('#message').val()
    }
  }]
});
```

demo -> **https://jsfiddle.net/2nwqa2jk/**

If you just provide `title: 'Vehicle ID:'+$("#vehicleID").val()+'\nDate Start:'` then this expression is evaluated once upon initialisation. If you pass a function this is executed when the PDF is generated.

Comment: I dont know why my pdfHtml5 does not appear I have checked I have all the .js files I tested with pdf these fileName: function() {
          return "TEST:"+$("#vehicleID").val()    
        },
        title: function() {
          return "Vehicle:"+$("#vehicleID").val()+"\nTEST"
        } but my file name also become what is in the title

Comment: I have updated the latest from this link https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html and also cleared the cache and cookies. But yet the same.

Comment: @Davidkondrad cant it work for the normal pdf function?

Comment: @Davidkondrad I have tested with pdf but both results become same the file name and title.

Comment: @user8012596, hmm - weird, works with `'pdf'` as well -> https://jsfiddle.net/2nwqa2jk/1/ click on "external resources" in the fiddle and see if you have any discrepancy with the versions (hold the mouse over the resources to see the version / link)

Comment: @Davidkondrad quite weird I tried this now filename: function() {
           var finalFinalName="JourneyData_"+endDateTimeFinal 
            return finalFinalName     
          },
          title: function() {
            return $('#vehicleID').val()
          } it updates well on the finalname but then the title on the page also becomes the same like the filename. Any reason for this similarity to happen

Comment: You do have 1.3.1 in all buttons files...? In particular buttons.datatables.js and buttons.html5.js.

Comment: @davidkondrad yes I have ensured both these are the latest ones. Now my title also becomes JourneyData_2017-07-06 2300 . I just wanted my filename this format it works nicely but then my title I want to put the vehicle id and starttime and end time.

Comment: Please create a fiddle where the behaviour is reproduced. I cannot keep guessing, if everything is right it must be something else causing the problem. Can you paste your code into the fiddle above and you get the same result as locally...?

Comment: @Davidkondrad the problem is that my results comes from the backend database. Maybe give me some time I prepare link to my website will that be ok?

Comment: @Davidkondrad I have updated my question with the link. Please click on the link and just press the submit button you will get data then please press on the pdf to export the data.

Comment: The link does not work. Sry I was latew to the party, have been out a few days to some events.

Comment: @Davidkondrad sorry my apology can you try now the link is up again. Just click on the submit button it will generate the data

Comment: @Davidkondrad could you access the new link I have put up ready?

Comment: @user8012596, you get an error "*Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined*" when the export is trigerred, in buttons.html5, but hard to debug since it is the minified version. Is it the 1.3.1 version of buttons.html5.js..?

Comment: @Davidkondrad yes I took this file from this link https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js which was you suggestion last week. Should I swap to the non min.js ?

Comment: **Your error is here** -> `return $('#vehicleID').val()` You do not have a `#vehicleID` element, therefore it returns `undefined`, therefore you get an `Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined` error upon `title` in buttons.html5.js, since `title` is `undefined`.

Comment: @Davidkondrad I have overcome that error. But I have this error return "Vehicle ID:".$('#vehicleID').val() . I need few more information at the title and few more other lines?